# Google adsense API - Get all alerts

Tags: node.js, google-api, adsense, google-api-nodejs-client, adsense-api

So I'm trying to make a NodeJs app, that checks regularly for any new Google Adsense alerts, The issue is that until now, It only shows one Alert, while there is more than 80 showing on my Adsense panel.

```
response = await google.adsense("v2").accounts.alerts.list({
         parent: "accounts/pub-1114210973959830",
      })
```

it only shown one Alert:

```
"data": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "name": "accounts/pub-1114210973959830/alerts/e82e227b-0ce2-31f4-8047-5eea5e2a6dc0",
        "severity": "WARNING",
        "message": "You have ad crawler errors, which can result in lost revenue.",
        "type": "crawler-errors"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Can you verify that the API user is the same user that you're logging into the  UI with? Also, note that the API does not return resolved alerts, only active ones.

Comment: Ah, that explains it, the alerts are closed, so that was the issue. Thank you for your help!